# No file at UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL after upgrading to Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, swift2

After upgrading my Swift video app to Swift 2.0/Xcode 7/iOS 9, everything works fine except getting videos from `UIImagePickerController`. All permissions check out for camera and library. I can get to both and record a new video or select an existing video from the library. However, when the delegate method `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is called, an `NSFileManager` tells me there is no file at the `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`. This is true both before and after calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated` on the `UIImagePickerController`.

It was working flawlessly before and there were no major code changes to accommodate the upgrades. I have found no other similar issues reported online, so I figure I must have screwed something up like folder permissions but I can't figure out what. I thought maybe using `NSAppTransportSecurity` had something to do with it as it relates to `file:///` URLs, but the issue persists in iOS 7, 8, and 9 regardless of whether or not that dictionary is present in my info.plist.

If anyone can give me some leads to look into I would greatly appreciate it. I've tried this on iPhones 6, 5s, & 4s with the same result. I do recall going round and round with "kUTTypeMovie" during the Swift 2 upgrades. The "[kUTTypeMovie as String]" below is the only thing I found that Xcode would accept. That could be a weak point, but I doubt it since it seems to work as expected. The only reason I mention it is that if you don't ask for a type, the app doesn't have permission to receive it.

**Additional information**

I am able to use UIImagePickerController to get images from the camera/library as normal. On a whim, I thought maybe I could get around this issue by just grabbing the original video and compressing it myself, but the NSFileManager tells me that there is no file at the UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL either. I don’t know how this could be possible unless my app is being denied access somehow.

- Log using code below: THERE IS NOT a file at:
  assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=22A4CFF1-BBC0-4084-990D-B217908F0616&ext=MOV
- This is so strange that I've filed a bug report with Apple.

**Relevant code here:**

```
 @IBAction func actionTakeVideo(sender: AnyObject) {
    if videoPickerController == nil {
        videoPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        videoPickerController.delegate = self
        videoPickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        videoPickerController.videoMaximumDuration = NSTimeInterval(maxVideoDuration-1)
        videoPickerController.allowsEditing = true
        videoPickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityType.TypeHigh
 }
```

...

```
// From Library
       let status:ALAuthorizationStatus = ALAssetsLibrary.authorizationStatus()
       if status != ALAuthorizationStatus.Authorized{
           print("Library not authorized: status != ALAuthorizationStatus.Authorized")
       } else {
           self.videoPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
           self.presentViewController(self.videoPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
```

...

```
//From Camera
      if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
            self.videoPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            self.videoPickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.Front
            self.presentViewController(self.videoPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
```

...

```
//Delegate
     func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
         let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager();
         let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL
         if manager.fileExistsAtPath(videoURL.absoluteString) {
             print("THERE IS a file at: \(videoURL.absoluteString)")
         } else {
             print("THERE IS NOT a file at: \(videoURL.absoluteString)") // ALWAYS LANDS HERE.
         }
     }
```

UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL is like, file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6754830D-ER98-31OL-GU34-78067GD908PI/tmp/trim.578E437C-EEBC-4BC5-AD5C-C351BD0822B2.MOV

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: There is no error thrown. The only evidence of the issue is when I try to access the video file - there is nothing there. If there are notifications I can observe to catch errors within the UIImagePickerController's internal compression or file transfer process or its underlying components, I am not aware of them.

Comment: Have you ever found out why it is so? Seems like in iOS 9 SDK the key UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL is not present anymore

Comment: I have the same problem. I can confirm that the UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL file is there. Using IExplorer, I can open the temp file on the device. Thought it could be a declarative permission issue in iOS 9, but I can't find anything to add to the PLIST to fix this. I am also using NSInputStream to read the file. It returns Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"

Comment: I am still waiting on Apple to respond to my bug report. Please add your own bug report at bugreport.apple.com so they will address this. Thanks.

Comment: Any updates? It´s showing "No such file or directory" for me too...

Comment: After upgrading to Xcode 7.2.1, this error no longer happens for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old but I stumbled upon the same error today.

The problem is that you're getting the file URL string from videoURL.absoluteString and passing it to NSFileManager's fileExistsAtPath method instead of a path. You should get the path to the file by reading NSURL's "path" property.

The file URL as read from videoURL.absoluteString looks like this:

> file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6754830D-ER98-31OL-GU34-78067GD908PI/tmp/trim.578E437C-EEBC-4BC5-AD5C-C351BD0822B2.MOV

The file path as read from videoURL.path would look like this:

> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6754830D-ER98-31OL-GU34-78067GD908PI/tmp/trim.578E437C-EEBC-4BC5-AD5C-C351BD0822B2.MOV

The following code:

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
         let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager();
         let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL
         if manager.fileExistsAtPath(videoURL.absoluteString) {
             print("THERE IS a file at: \(videoURL.absoluteString)")
         } else {
             print("THERE IS NOT a file at: \(videoURL.absoluteString)") // ALWAYS LANDS HERE.
         }
     }
```

Must be changed to:

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
         let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager();
         let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL
         if manager.fileExistsAtPath(videoURL.path) {
             print("THERE IS a file at: \(videoURL.path)")
         } else {
             print("THERE IS NOT a file at: \(videoURL.path)") // ALWAYS LANDS HERE.
         }
     }
```

And keeping in mind that UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL might not be present:

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
         if let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL {
             if FileManager.default.fileExistsAtPath(videoURL.path) {
                 print("THERE IS a file at: \(videoURL.path)")
             } else {
                 print("THERE IS NOT a file at: \(videoURL.path)") // ALWAYS LANDS HERE.
             }
         }
     }
```